# how to upload images (their binary version) to the server using AJAX mimicking a multipart request?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, multipartform-data

In my application, if a user clicks on the button to take a screenshot, a method in an `activeX` control is called which takes the screenshot, converts it into bytes (**64-bit encoded string**), and I am able to access that 64-bit encoded string in javascript, and I use it to show the user a preview of the image (the `src` property of an `img` tag is set with the string).

Now, when the user clicks on the '**Save**' button of the preview, I wish to send the image to the server using `ajax`. Now, the problem is that I have just the binary string of the file, but I want to send the image as a `multipart` request (as if it had been uploaded using `<input type="file"/>`. Any way possible to do that ? The only condition is that the image should be sent as `multipart` request, so that I can receive it using standard techniques of handling multipart uploads at the server.

I can live with an IE-specific solution too :)

Comment: Can you show us some code that you have tried to work on?

Comment: Which version of IE do you want to support?

Answer (score 0):

You can't send multi-part information through AJAX, but you can work around that. You make a form on the page:

```
<form name="img_form" target="img_iframe" action="..." method="..." enctype="multipart/form">
</form>

<iframe name="img_iframe" id="img_iframe"></iframe>
```

In your return data that will get loaded into img_iframe, you can set all kinds of return values using hidden fields or a link to the new file.

You can set an onLoad event like so:

```
$('iframe#img_iframe').on('load', function(event) {
    var iframe_content = ($.browser.msie ? $(event.target.contentWindow.document) : $(event.target.contentDocument));

    /* Do Stuff */
});
```

That's assuming you know how to set the correct data to be submitted in the form.

Comment: I don't understand. How will this help me in transferring a binary image file through the ajax request ?

Comment: You can send the base64 data however you like through AJAX such as $.post(url, {'data[Image][generated_image]':base64_encoded_binary_data}, function(data) {});

however, you *can't* send a file field through AJAX as multipart data. Simply won't work. The workaround answer I posted will allow you to upload a file field in an AJAX-like fashion. One question for you... is this image being generated from a Flash/Flex application? If so, another option is to use ActionScript's functionality to submit the data directly.